# .htaccess to Redirect all Pages to one Domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, architecture, seo

I have one site that I never perused and I might as well redirect all pages there to my current project.  I am currently able to redirect to a mirror url, which means only the home page redirects to the new home page.

But how can I do it so that all the pages on the old site redirect to http://www.comehike.com

Here is my current .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.comehike.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: ps - any idea why the blink tags didn't work? :)

Comment: Are your old url of type http://old-domain.com/?something ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: That didn't quite work.  This url http://www.womensanfrancisco.com/san_francisco_women_exercise.php still redirects to a mirror url.  Any idea how to make it go to just http://www.comehike.com  ?

Comment: What does the HTTP_HOST stand for?  I am not sure what to replace that with.

Comment: It matches a magic Apache variable that indicates what the value of the Host header in HTTP was.

Comment: Ah cool, how do I find out what my value for that variable is? :)

Comment: It won't be fixed; it'll depend on the HTTP request. Fortunately, it's pretty obvious from the URL what a particular request will be.

Comment: (more pragmatically, old-domain.com is the domain you're redirecting FROM).

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.new.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```